# Why don't the Uniswap and Kyberswap app values match code-returned values?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, cryptocurrency

Using the base code from the price discovery bot:  https://github.com/dappuniversity/price-bot (Tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77G_-cMayRU&list=RDCMUCY0xL8V6NzzFcwzHCgB8orQ&index=2)
, I checked my output values against the app values for Uniswap and Kyberswap and they don't match.

[image]

In addition, it seems that the values returned by the Node.JS application don't really change as I run the application which leads me to believe these are not really live results?

Answer (score 0):

The linked JS script queries the exchange contracts directly but the UIs read possibly cached and aggregated data from an API endpoint.

Specifically the script [calls](https://github.com/dappuniversity/price-bot/blob/master/index.js#L39) `getEthToTokenInputPrice()` function on the Uniswap pair contract, returning the live response from the blockchain copy of your node provider.

However, when you input a number to the UI, it queries some endpoint that is most likely cached. And based on the response, I'm also guessing it's returning an aggregated price for the specified `blockNumber`. It might also take suggested transaction fees and other parameters into account and calculate them to the final displayed price.

One of the reasons behind using non-live data on the exchange UI might be lowering the usage of their own node or 3rd party node provider. Uniswap UI is using Infura as a provider for some other requests, which has pricing plans based on usage.

[image: Screenshot of the non-live response]